# What is the right way to handle error pages in moqui

Tags: moqui

To redirect user to an error page I am adding entry in web.xml for 401 (Unauthorized) error code. But I don't find it correct. As, I am adding following code in web.xml which is in framework.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/myapp/Error/Error401.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And, What if there are more than one component in my application and I want to redirect on different error pages on same error code as per component. Please guide me as to how can I achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.